Linux Perf PMU Events does not have UNCORE_CXL events in Sapphire Rapids
I'm using Linux 6.5.0 on Xeon 6438, and I noticed that there is a uncore_cxl.json file under tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/sapphirerapids/ , which defines many cxl related events, but I can't find them by perf list, so how to access these events?
By the way, events listed in tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/sapphirerapids/uncore_*.json(except cxl) can all be seen in perf.
perf list | grep cxl :
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_hit_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_hit_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_crdmorph_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drd_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drd_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drd_opt_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drd_opt_pref_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drd_pref_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drd_pref_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_drdmorph_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_llcprefcode_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_llcprefdata_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_llcprefdata_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_llcprefrfo_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_llcprefrfo_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_rfo_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_rfo_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_rfo_pref_cxl_acc
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_rfo_pref_cxl_acc_local
  unc_cha_tor_inserts.ia_miss_rfomorph_cxl_acc
***********

tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/sapphirerapids/uncore_cxl.json:
[
    {
        "BriefDescription": "Counts the number of lfclk ticks",
        "Counter": "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7",
        "EventCode": "0x01",
        "EventName": "UNC_CXLCM_CLOCKTICKS",
        "PerPkg": "1",
        "UMask": "0x2",
        "Unit": "CXLCM"
    },
    {
        "BriefDescription": "Number of Allocation to Mem Rxx AGF 0",
        "Counter": "4,5,6,7",
        "EventCode": "0x43",
        "EventName": "UNC_CXLCM_RxC_AGF_INSERTS.CACHE_DATA",
        "Experimental": "1",
        "PerPkg": "1",
        "UMask": "0x8",
        "Unit": "CXLCM"
    },
    {
        "BriefDescription": "Number of Allocation to Cache Req AGF0",
        "Counter": "4,5,6,7",
        "EventCode": "0x43",
        "EventName": "UNC_CXLCM_RxC_AGF_INSERTS.CACHE_REQ0",
        "Experimental": "1",
        "PerPkg": "1",
        "UMask": "0x1",
        "Unit": "CXLCM"
    },
    {
        "BriefDescription": "Number of Allocation to Cache Rsp AGF",
        "Counter": "4,5,6,7",
        "EventCode": "0x43",
        "EventName": "UNC_CXLCM_RxC_AGF_INSERTS.CACHE_REQ1",
        "Experimental": "1",
        "PerPkg": "1",
        "UMask": "0x2",
        "Unit": "CXLCM"
    },



The events you listed using "perf list | grep cxl". you can find detailed info in "/linux/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/sapphirerapids/uncore-cache.json". The Unit of these events is "CHA" (Cache/Home Agent). You can use Intel PCM subtools "pcm-raw" to monitor these events.
https://github.com/intel/pcm/blob/master/doc/PCM_RAW_README.md

Otherwise, "perf list | grep cxl" has other outputs.
cxl_pmu_mem0.0/clock_ticks/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_act/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_casrd/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_caswr/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_pre/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_refresh/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_rfm/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/ddr_selfrefreshent/                 [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_meminv/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_meminvnt/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_memrd/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_memrddata/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_memrdfwd/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_memspecrd/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_req_memwrfwd/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_rwd_memwr/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/m2s_rwd_memwrptl/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/s2m_drs_memdata/                    [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/s2m_ndr_cmp/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/s2m_ndr_cmpe/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem0.0/s2m_ndr_cmps/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/clock_ticks/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_act/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_casrd/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_caswr/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_pre/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_refresh/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_rfm/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/ddr_selfrefreshent/                 [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_meminv/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_meminvnt/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_memrd/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_memrddata/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_memrdfwd/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_memspecrd/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_req_memwrfwd/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_rwd_memwr/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/m2s_rwd_memwrptl/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/s2m_drs_memdata/                    [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/s2m_ndr_cmp/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/s2m_ndr_cmpe/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  cxl_pmu_mem1.0/s2m_ndr_cmps/                       [Kernel PMU event]

They can be monitored using "perf stat -e event_name", the detailed info about  them in https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf/cxl.html#cxl-performance-monitoring-unit-cpmu. And I also think that CPMU events is what uncore_cxl.json described.
